# Reindexing a specific level of a MultiIndex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, reindex

I have a DataFrame with two indices and would like to reindex it by one of the indices.

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Instruments to download
tickers = ['AAPL']

# Online source one should use
data_source = 'yahoo'

# Data range
start_date = '2000-01-01'
end_date = '2018-01-09'

# Load the desired data
panel_data = data.DataReader(tickers, data_source, start_date, end_date).to_frame()
panel_data.head()
```

[image: Screenshot]

The reindexing goes as follows:

```
# Get just the adjusted closing prices
adj_close = panel_data['Adj Close']

# Gett all weekdays between start and end dates
all_weekdays = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='B')

# Align the existing prices in adj_close with our new set of dates
adj_close = adj_close.reindex(all_weekdays, method="ffill")
```

The last line gives the following error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
```

This is because the DataFrame index is a list of tuples:

```
panel_data.index[0]
```

```
(Timestamp('2018-01-09 00:00:00'), 'AAPL')
```

Is it possible to reindex `adj_close`? By the way, if I don't convert the Panel object to a DataFrame using `to_frame()`, the reindexing works as it is. But it seems that Panel objects are deprecated...

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `adj_close.reindex(all_weekdays, level=0).ffill()`?

Comment: Perfect! That worked. I'd be glad to accept it as an answer. Thanks a lot for the quick response!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're looking to reindex on a certain *level*, then `reindex` accepts a `level` argument you can pass -

```
adj_close.reindex(all_weekdays, level=0)
```

When passing a `level` argument, you cannot pass a `method` argument at the same time (`reindex` throws a `TypeError`), so you can chain a `ffill` call after -

```
adj_close.reindex(all_weekdays, level=0).ffill()
```