# Reindexing only level of a MultiIndex dataframe, reindex() broken?

Tags: python, pandas

I try to reindex a dataframe with two or more indices on one level only, but using `.reindex()` with the `level` argument, as I have seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48179385/8719405) seems to do nothing instead of the expected behavior.

Here is the code I try to make work:

```
import pandas as pd

dtest = pd.DataFrame([['Martin', 'room_1', 3],
                      ['Martin', 'room_2', 2],
                      ['Georges', 'room_2', 4],
                      ['Georges', 'room_1', 12]],
                     columns=['name', 'room', 'time_spent'])
dtest.set_index(['name', 'room',], inplace=True)
display(dtest)
print(dtest.reindex(
    ['room_1', 'room_2', 'room_3'], level=1, fill_value=0))
```

which outputs

```
                time_spent
name    room              
Martin  room_1           3
        room_2           2
Georges room_1          12
        room_2           4
```

whereas the output I am expecting is

```
                time_spent
name    room              
Martin  room_1           3
        room_2           2
        room_3           0
Georges room_1          12
        room_2           4
        room_3           0
```

`reindex()` literally didn't do anything.

Did I miss an important detail on the use of `reindex` or is something broken?

I'm using the last version of pandas with Python 3.6.7 (v3.6.7:6ec5cf24b7, Oct 20 2018, 03:02:14).

**Edit after accepting the answer**

I have accepted @anky_91's answer who actually provides two different solutions. As my actual use case involves more levels in the multi-index, let me underline the behaviour of his two solutions with more levels.

The starting dataframe is now given by

```
import pandas as pd

dtest2 = pd.DataFrame([['2020-01-05', 'Martin', 'room_1', 3],
                      ['2020-01-05', 'Martin', 'room_2', 2],
                      ['2020-01-06', 'Georges', 'room_2', 4],
                      ['2020-01-06', 'Georges', 'room_1', 12]],
                     columns=['date', 'name', 'room', 'time_spent'])
dtest2.set_index(['date', 'name', 'room',], inplace=True)
print(dtest2)
```

which outputs

```
                           time_spent
date       name    room              
2020-01-05 Martin  room_1           3
                   room_2           2
2020-01-06 Georges room_2           4
                   room_1          12
```

The first solution adapted to this case is

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((dtest2.index.get_level_values(0).unique(),
                                  dtest2.index.get_level_values(1).unique(),
                                  ['room_1', 'room_2', 'room_3']
                            ))
final_first_solution = dtest2.reindex(mux,fill_value=0)
print(final_first_solution)
```

which outputs

```
                           time_spent
2020-01-05 Martin  room_1           3
                   room_2           2
                   room_3           0
           Georges room_1           0
                   room_2           0
                   room_3           0
2020-01-06 Martin  room_1           0
                   room_2           0
                   room_3           0
           Georges room_1          12
                   room_2           4
                   room_3           0
```

This is not my desired output as Martin needs to only appear on 2020-01-05 and Georges only appears on 2020-01-06. In other words, I only want to expand the index on the last level `room`.
However, I managed to adapt the second solution to get my desired output:

```
final_second_solution = dtest2.unstack((0, 1)).reindex(['room_1', 'room_2', 'room_3'], fill_value=0)\
        .stack((-2, -1)).swaplevel(i=-1, j=0).swaplevel(i=1, j=0).sort_index()
print(final_second_solution)
```

correctly gives me

```
                           time_spent
date       name    room              
2020-01-05 Martin  room_1         3.0
                   room_2         2.0
                   room_3         0.0
2020-01-06 Georges room_1        12.0
                   room_2         4.0
                   room_3         0.0
```

hence why I accepted the answer. Thanks!

**Edit 2 for a different use case**

After testing more, the above solution fails when you are not adding a new room, but instead want to complete all rooms appearing in the dataframe. But the solution is simpler, as in this case `unstack` already creates the missing lines so we just have to use `fillna` instead of `reindex`. The following code

```
import pandas as pd

dtest3 = pd.DataFrame([['2020-01-05', 'Martin', 'room_1', 3],
                      ['2020-01-06', 'Georges', 'room_2', 4]],
                     columns=['date', 'name', 'room', 'time_spent'])
dtest3.set_index(['date', 'name', 'room',], inplace=True)
print(dtest3)
final_third_solution = dtest3.unstack((0, 1)).fillna(0).stack((-2, -1)).reorder_levels([1,2,0]).sort_index()
print(final_third_solution)
```

hence gives the desired outcome

```
                           time_spent
date       name    room              
2020-01-05 Martin  room_1         3.0
                   room_2         0.0
2020-01-06 Georges room_1         0.0
                   room_2         4.0
```

(I have also included the suggestion in the comments of using `reorder_levels` instead of using multiple `swaplevel`).

Using `.fillna(0).reindex(..., fill_value=0)` should encompass the two cases where you want to complete and add new elements.

Comment: So it appears that the `level` argument of `reindex` works to reindex **only** existing levels values; it cannot enlarge the DataFrame by creating new rows. So if you reindexed with `['room_3', 'room_2', 'room_1']` it would re-order, but not enlarge. Might be a bug, or just an issue with a MultIndex being tuples.

Comment: You can use `reorder_levels` instead of two `swaplevel`, like this: `dtest2.unstack([0,1]).reindex(['room_1','room_2','room_3'], fill_value=0)\
      .stack([-2,-1]).reorder_levels([1,2,0]).sort_index()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would need to create a multi index for this using [`pd.MultiIndex.from_product()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and [`get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
mux=(pd.MultiIndex.from_product((dtest.index.get_level_values(0).unique()
                             ,['room_1', 'room_2', 'room_3'])))
final=dtest.reindex(mux,fill_value=0)
```

---

```
                time_spent
Martin  room_1           3
        room_2           2
        room_3           0
Georges room_1          12
        room_2           4
        room_3           0
```

If you want to just add another index with the existing indexes , use [`Index.union`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) to the `from_product()` arg:

```
mux=(pd.MultiIndex.from_product((dtest.index.get_level_values(0).unique()
        ,dtest.index.get_level_values(1).unique().union(['room3'],sort=False))))
final=dtest.reindex(mux,fill_value=0)

                time_spent
Martin  room_1           3
        room_2           2
        room_3           0
Georges room_1          12
        room_2           4
        room_3           0
```

---

Adding another metod with [`stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html):

```
final=dtest.unstack(0).reindex(['room_1', 'room_2', 'room_3']
                     ,fill_value=0).stack().swaplevel().sort_index()
```

---

```
                time_spent
name    room              
Georges room_1          12
        room_2           4
        room_3           0
Martin  room_1           3
        room_2           2
        room_3           0
```

Comment: Your first solution doesn't generalize well if there are more levels in the MultiIndex.

Your second solution does, so I have accepted your answer.

See my Edit for the case with more levels.